# Как (технически) процессор выполняет команду int 21h (ассемблер TASM), тема прерывания

Tags: ассемблер, прерывания

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как он это делает поэтапно. Например: при выполнении команды PUSH AX значение SP уменьшается на 2, после чего значение AX помещается в память по адресу SS:SP.
Очень долго пыталась найти на просторах интернета, но никак не удалось обогатить свои знания столь ценной информацией. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: сначала надо понять, как работают прерывания, а команда int вызывает прерывание программно. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Команда int 21h работает точно так же, как любая другая команда int:

Передаёт управление от одной ячеки программного сегмента к другой. Причём эти ячейки могут лежать в одном сегменте кода, могут - в разных.

Для того, что бы знать, куда передавать управление, у процессора есть таблица векторов прерываний. Если мы пишем int 21h, то это означает, что надо перейти по адресу, указанному в строке 21h этой таблицы.

Comment: Просто разработчики IBM PC договорились, что по этому адресу должен быть расположен программный обработчик прерываний BIOS. 

Адрес "откуда" пришло прерывание запоминается процессором в стеке. Обработчик прерывания достаёт этот адрес из стека, и смотрит, что за код лежит в байте, следующем за байтом, содержащим 21h.

Comment: А там должен лежать номер функции BIOS, которую просит выполнить прикладной программист. А за номер функции располагаются операнды этой функции.

Это, в самых общих чертах. Там можно много говорить по сохранение/восстановление, но это не так уж и важно, с точки зрения прикладного программиста.

Comment: Можете почитать [здесь](http://www.logix.cz/michal/doc/i386/chp09-00.htm). Прерывания — это очень обширная тема.